# Daily-Scheduler, Open source / Freeware, Full Version, Offline, for Windows

Tags: gratis, open-source, offline

When I search for freeware I find crippleware (software that half its basic features have been removed and provided only in the paid version).

When I search for open source I find pseudo-open ones, or online (who wants to share his/her personal/business tasks with some random obscure company?)

Min requirements:

1. Open source, or freeware.
2. Full version (no 'pro' features, no optional paid version).
3. Standalone, downloadable (offline).
4. No adware.
5. Not a Google or Microsoft product. The smaller the publisher, the better.
6. Not a webpage-less program like 'PIM Xtreme'.
7. No registration requirement.
8. Non java based.
9. Notification/reminder alarm for each task.
10. Daily repeatable tasks.
11. Daily task view and editor.
12. Half-our time resolution or better
13. Different color set for each task.
14. Runs on Windows 7.